# Server monitoring

Tags: nagios, monitoring

I need a server monitoring tool that does the following
 - Notifications when services or sites go down
 - SLA Reports
 - Inventory Managment
 - Centralized Logs
 - Monitor local and remote servers

I have looked into using Groundwork Opensource, Splunk, Spiceworks which seperatly seem to do some of these tasks, but I would prefer not to have so many tools, anybody know any one tools that can do this all?

BTW My servers are not in a domain environment so tools that require that will not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your input Mark,
I have decided to go with OpenAudit for the inventory management and GWOS for the server monitoring with the ArcSight Logger 5.0 plugin for Log monitoring

Answer (score 3):

Check out this link:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems
Which does a comparison of quite a few pieces of software

Answer (score 1):

[Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) is the one we use that does all those things, I believe that Nagios would also do them (with a few plugins). It runs on Linux, but we have a 95% Windows environment, but that's no problem. We just installed it on  a small Linux VM and it has Windows agents.

Comment: Groundwork Opensource is bascially Nagios with a bunch of plugins, but it doesnt seem to do Inventory Managment or Log managment without expensive plugins

Comment: @cpg - Zabbix may still be worth researching. I'm not 100% sure about its log management, but it does do inventory management and can even map your network out if you put in a bit of work.

Comment: Do you have any comments on Zabbix inventory managment? It seems it will not automatically create the inventory list you have to manually populate the fields?

Comment: @cpg - there is an auto-detect function, but I've never used it.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but is the auto-detect function only used for finding machines to monitor not populating inventory charts?

Comment: @cpg - it could be, but given that that surely the majority of items going into the inventory could be auto-detected, which would at least remove a large amount of work. That said, as I mentioned, I've never actually used that function of Zabbix.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios seems to be the option that many people prefer, but Hyperic HQ, Groundwork, and Zenoss are other options. This article breaks down the differences pretty well. http://www.futurehosting.com/open-source-server-monitoring-what-are-your-options/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.